# C: Sorting Big Data; Not in Memory

Tags: c, sorting, bigdata

I'm learning to work with large amounts of data.

I've generated a file of 10,000,000 ints. I want to perform a number of sorts on the data and time the sorts (maybe plot the values for performance analysis?) but I've never worked with big data before and don't know how to sort (say, even bubble sort!) data that isn't in memory! I want to invoke the program like so:

```
./mySort < myDataFile > myOutFile
```

How would I go about sorting data that can't fit into a linked list, or array?

Comment: Read it into memory, sort it, then write it out again.

Comment: Your CPU can't even compare two `int` values when they aren't in the main memory. You absolutely need to get the data into the memory before sorting it.

Comment: Use a merge sort algorithm.

Comment: I'd wager the 'big data' issue that needs to be solved here is sorting the list when it won't all fit into memory _at the same time_. Otherwise, yes, the previous comments make sense.

Comment: 10,000,000 `int` is only about 78MB of data on a x64 system with 64bit `int`, half that with 32bit int. That isn't an unreasonable hit unless you're on a system that is *very* constrained for resources (embedded, etc.). Any in-place O(nlogn) algorithm should do you nicely. When you say "can't fit into an array" you're not talking about a local automatic array, `int bigarray[10000000]` right? That would be ludicrous. You need to *heap*-allocate the memory for this.

Comment: To everyone commenting about this: There are cases where you need a disk aware sorting method. What if the file was 1TB? Even though 10,000,000 ints may not be a lot for many systems, the user may be on some architecture have some constraint. It isn't really helpful to say "just put it in memory" unless you also include an answer to the actual question along with this hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of algorithms for performing this type of operation.  They all fall under the general heading of [External Sorting](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

One of the best references on this, though rather technical and dense is Donald Knuth's treatment of tape sorting algorithms.  Back in the day where data was stored on tape and could only be read sequentially and then written out to other tapes this kind of sorting was often done by repeatedly shuffling data back and forth between different tape drives.

Depending upon the size and type of dataset you are working with it may be worthwhile to make use of either a dedicated database to load the data into, or to make use of a cloud based service like [Google's BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/).  BigQuery has no cost to upload and download your dataset, you just pay for the processing.  The first TB of processed data each month is free and you have less than even one GB of data.

Edit: Here's a very nice set of [undergraduate lecture notes](http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs321/lectures/external_sorting.html) on external sorting algorithms. http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs321/lectures/external_sorting.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use external sorting

Bring in part of data at a time , sort it in memory and then merge it

More details here

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting